# Stop WordPress from auto updating

Tags: automatic-updates

I have a site that works in 4.1.3 which I have a backup of though when I reinstall the site it auto updates to 4.1.4 which then breaks parts of the site.

I did add this to the wp-config file in the first 30 seconds of reinstalling but the site still auto updated, any tips on waht to do?

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Comment: Are you using any auto-installers like Softaculous?

Comment: Just a note: [update to WP 4.1.4 fix a potencial XSS vulnerability](http://www.wpbeginner.com/news/wordpress-4-2-1-security-release-fixes-zero-day-xss-vulnerability-update-now/). You should be happy. ;). Anyway, your code should code. Any more info to provide?

Comment: On a sidenote - it would be great if you could report the issue with the official WordPress support channels as this just being a security update it should really not be breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) you could try this with a filter too like `add_filter( 'auto_update_core', '__return_false' );` to add: in the themes functions.php of course, not in the wp-config.

Comment: The filter or `WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE` constant set to `false` in wp-config should have the same effect. In fact, `WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE` constant should override any updates filter.

Comment: That is correct, but as it didn't work for some reason, I'm just offering another way :)

Comment: I will give it a go, might be a case of having to apply the code before reinstalling even though I do it in like 30 seconds.

Comment: @jimihenrik the reason why it didn't work is what should be addressed in the answer (from my point of view) as it makes no sense that one way work and another not. In fact, there can be tons of reasons why the filter wouldn't work but very few why the constant not; the constant take precedence over the filter and makes any filter stop working.

Comment: I do agree. Although without knowing quite a bit more, I can't really say why it's not working. Like you say, there can be a multitude of reasons. And I agree on that too that if the constant didn't work, ofc the filter shouldn't work either. Didn't really think it through when posting.

Comment: What eneded up working was adding this before the reinstall, even though before I added it like 30 seconds after it still went ahead:

define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );